# How to show suggestion list on google map search?

Tags: android, iphone, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to show suggestion list same as google maps application.

I found some api on google developer site but they dont return same result as google maps application.

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchRequests

check this screen shot for more.

Its finding using current location, my location is jaipur,rajasthan,india.

[image]

Comment: Whic API service you using it's all based on the parameter you are passing to the API. Then it will return the desired results

Answer (score 1):

You need to use third party library API for this. [FourSuqare](https://developer.foursquare.com/resources/libraries) provides the most efficient and largest database of location based API for this. IT uses type ahead.  I would recommend to use their [iOS SDK](https://github.com/baztokyo/foursquare-ios-api) or Android SDK.

The also offer REST web services. [Here](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/) is a complete documentation for the same.

What you are looking for is this [API](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/suggestcompletion)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a handy library that utilizes the Google Places autocomplete API ... or you can "inspire" from here... https://github.com/chenyuan/SPGooglePlacesAutocomplete

The result:
[image]

Comment: its not look like my screen shot..data should be same as my screen shot.

Comment: aaaa, you want to look like your screen shoot, I understood now

Comment: yup.. same to same... :)